# Alternative to this; STDBOOL not found

Tags: c, visual-c++

I am trying to read a key hit and then stop a code. In C.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool starting()
{
  char c;
    if (kbhit())
    {
        c=getch();
        if (c=="S"||c=="s")
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
  while(!starting)
  {
    printf("line 1");
    delay(100);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Without `stdbool.h`, it says errors like

```
syntax error: identifier 'starting', 
syntax error: ";"
syntax error: ")"
'starting': undeclared identifier
```

With stdbool.h, it says file not found. My compiler is the one that comes with Visual Studio 2010.

Any suggestion how to remove this? How can I still use a function that returns a boolean value?

**ADDED**
sorry! for the short comment added. resolved mostly. Thanks all

**Added**
More Errors:
After Compiling: it reads:

```
filename.obj unresolved external symbol _delay referenced in function _main.
```

What should I do?

Comment: `typedef unsigned char bool; #define false 0 #define true 1`

Comment: Or just write it in C++. The C compiler in VS is crap. Even crappier than the C++ one (which also is).

Comment: If you're trying to call the function `starting` inside that while, you're missing a `()`.

Comment: @Mat, care to explain?

Comment: @DavidRF: `while(!starting)` tests the function pointer, not the function's return.

Comment: This is in no way a compiler issue, so why is it "crap" here? It's a stdlib issue if you want, but the compiler is working perfectly fine here.

Comment: @Mat, are you sure? if `starting` returns false there is no infinite loop

Comment: @DavidRF: `starting` is a function identifier. `starting()` is a function call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using boolean values in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921539/using-boolean-values-in-c)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656874/where-is-stdbool-h and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548521/trying-to-use-include-stdbool-h-in-vs-2010.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`stdbool.h` is introduced in `C99`, and Visual Studio doesn't support `C99`. You can define the types yourself. One possible way is:

```
typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0
```

Comment: you forgot semicolon after bool.

Comment: Can you have a look at last sentence i added?

Comment: @user2178841 Where is the function `delay` defined?

Comment: VS2013 (and VS2014 CTPs) support C99. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/18/crt-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Three problems at once:

- C doesn't know `bool` as a type of its own, but you can define it (e.g. through `stdbool.h` or just by using a `typedef` to any other integral type (usually `unsigned char` or `int`; this might be a question of memory usage vs. performance based).
- MSVC is known for not having all the `std**.h` headers, especially older versions. So you most likely just don't have `stdbool.h` in VS 2010 (the reason for the file not found error).
- You're missing brackets in this expression: `while(!starting)`.

Comment: Do you happen to have born after 1999?

Comment: No, I just happend to read only half a post from time to time. :P