# Error while installing census python module: visual studio 9.0 does not compile jellyfish

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, python-2.7, census

I am running a 64-bit Windows 7 machine with Python 2.7 and am trying to install the census python module (version 0.7) found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/census/). I have Visual Studio Express 2008 (Version 9.0) installed, as well as versions 8, 11, and 12. When I try to install the module, it exits with a fatal error.

When I run the command prompt `pip install -U census`, these are the last few lines I get before the error:

```
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    C:\Programfiles (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c
/nologo /0x /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Users\user\Anaconda\include -IC:\User
s\user\Anaconda\PC /Tcjellyfishmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.wim-amd64-2.7\Release\
jellyfishmodule.obj
    jellyfishmodule.c 
    c: \users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-orcdrr\jellyfish\jellyfish.h
(4) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdbool.h': No such file 
or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC
\\BIN\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

The same error occurs when I am in the census-0.7 directory and enter the prompt `python setup.py install`

I have tried the fix [here](http://blog.victorjabur.com/2011/06/05/compiling-python-2-7-modules-on-windows-32-and-64-using-msvc-2008-express/), but it does not work. When I am in the census-0.7 directory and enter the prompt `python setup.py build --compiler msvc`, as the fix suggests, I get the following error message:

```
running build
running build_py
file census.py (for module census) not found
file census.py (for module census) not found
```

This leads me to believe there may be something wrong with the census module source code. Does anyone have experience solving this error in Python 2.7 on 64-bit machines or have experience installing the census module? I am a relatively novice programmer, so if there is an easy or obvious fix, I'm probably not seeing it.

Comment: VC 14 has more C99 support, including the `_Bool` type and stdbool.h, but I haven't tried using it to build 2.7 extension modules. You could also use MinGW (gcc fully supports C99).

Comment: You might be able to work around the problem by defining your own `stdbool.h`. See question [_Where is stdbool.h?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656874/where-is-stdbool-h)

Comment: @eryksun Installed MinGW and found same error message.

Comment: @martineau where would I define `stdbool.h`?

Comment: You might be able to get by with just putting it in the folder where the source file referencing it is. Otherwise, put it where Visual Studio keeps its own.